# Неправильный connectionString при подключении к SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Делаю самый простой консольный проект, что бы посмотреть как работать с SQLite.

Добавляю из Nuget пакет System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64), который автоматом тянет EF6 и Linq для него. Создаю простейший код для тестирования.

```
public class Human 
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class HContext : DbContext
{
    public HContext() : base("mydb") { }
    public DbSet<Human> Humans { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HContext ctx = new HContext();

        ctx.Humans.Add(new Human() { ID = 1, Name = "Patrik" });
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Отлично, все работает и запускается, но база создается в каталоге %UserProfile%. Добавляю в файл конфигурации connectionString, что бы база создавалась в директории приложения и получаю ошибку.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mydb" connectionString="data source =.\mydb.sqlite;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

> Additional information: An error occurred while getting provider
>   information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework
>   using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for
>   details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Пробовал другие варианты, эффект тот же, поисковики молчат как партизаны. В связи с этим вопрос, как правильно прописать connectionString?

---

UPD

Так же в файле конфигурации есть System.Data.SQLite.EF6.
Но при попытке подключить его в connectionString получаю такую ошибку.

> Additional information: Unable to determine the provider name for
>   provider factory of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'. Make sure
>   that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the
>   application config.

Comment: Или можно ответить на свой же вопрос и потом принять свое же решение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не помогло, но навело на нужные мысли)) Ответ в теле вопроса, а сам вопрос закрою через Ваш ответ.

Comment: Alex Krass, не надо отвечать в теле вопроса. На этом сайте так не принято.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ладно, перевел в отдельный ответ. Хотя как по мне в теле вопроса тоже неплохо бы смотрелось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо указать провайдера для SQLite вместо `System.Data.SqlClient`. `System.Data.SqlClient` - это провайдер для MS SQL Server.

Скорее всего, нужный вам провайдер будет называться `System.Data.SQLite`. Уточните в своем же конфигурационном файле - установленный вами пакет должен был добавить в него регистрацию своего провайдера.

---

Если все еще получаете ошибку - посмотрите `InnerException`. EF обожает прятать причину ошибки где-то внутри, иногда под несколькими "слоями" внешних исключений.

Comment: Да, после второго дня войны с ним мозги уже едут. По умолчанию там есть System.Data.SQLite.EF6, но он тоже выдает ошибку, если я указываю в качестве конфига его. Уже просто сил мыслить не хватает, может я где-то упустил сам SQLite? Выложил полный лист конфига.

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо. Там регистрация в EF провайдера  SQLite происходит через SQLite.EF6, чего я никак не ожидал. Вот и бился в ошибки все это время.

Answer (score 2):

Надо было подключаться через System.Data.SQLite.EF6, при этом в самом EF зарегистрировать еще System.Data.SQLite через System.Data.SQLite.EF6: `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />`

Финальный взлетевший конфиг выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mydb" connectionString="data source =.\mydb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```